# Production Python Logging

Tags: python, logging

I'm having some issues with logging on the production server. My settings.py looks like this:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    # Log to a text file that can be rotated by logrotate
    'logfile': {
        'class': 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler',
        'filename': 'logs/main.log',
        'formatter': 'simple',
        'mode': 'w',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    # Again, default Django configuration to email unhandled exceptions
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['logfile'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    # Might as well log any errors anywhere else in Django
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['logfile'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    # Your own app - this assumes all your logger names start with "myapp."
    'myapp': {
        'handlers': ['logfile'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True
    },
},
}
```

If I test it on the localhost I get:

```
2017-11-12 19:16:33,700 - django.server - INFO - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200
```

However if I test on the production server with nginx, gunicorn I get:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.googleapis.com
```

Those are really just the first line. My question is why am I getting 2 different outputs?

I can provide any other information as necessary? Is there a logging configuration that possibly overriding the one in the settings.py file?

Are there specific production logging configurations that need to happen?

Any help would be appreciated.... Hopefully someone has had this error or problem before.

EDIT: I'm using mode 'w' and on the localhost, my logfile is cleared if I reload the server, on the production side, it is not cleared.

Does this mean that I need to restart/reload gunicorn?

Answer (score 1):

Restarting and reloading gunicorn fixed the problem. WOW lol